# Strange python's comparison behaviour

Tags: python, compare

I have a sample code looking like this, values (position = 2, object.position = 3) :

```
    new_position = position
    old_position = object.position    

    logging.debug("1. new_position: %s, old_position: %s" % (new_position, old_position))

    if old_position != new_position:
        logging.debug("old position other than new position")
        if new_position > old_position:
            logging.debug("Why am I here ?")
```

and now the debug:

```
DEBUG 1. new_position: 2, old_position: 3
DEBUG 2. old position other than new position
DEBUG Why am I here?
```

Comment: Change the `%s` specifiers to `%r` and then post the output from that.

Comment: btw, you shouldn't use the name `object`, as that refers to the built-in type `object`, and it could confuse your program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's probably because you are comparing different incompatible types (e.g. strings and integers). If so, then the order depends on the alphabetical order of the type names.

```
>>> '2' > 3
True
```

This applies to Python 2.x. In Python 3.x this will raise a `TypeError` instead.

Comment: of course I thought about it jsut after submitting post. thx anyway !

Comment: @mastodon - IMHO, it's best to always print out `repr` (aka `%r`) rather than (or in addition to) versions converted to strings (aka `str` or `%s) when you're trying to debug things.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure `old_position` and `new_position` are integers? Any object can be made to print `'2'` and `'3'` when using `%s`... even when they implement comparisons in totally different way.

Try `%r` instead.

Answer (score -2):

assuming a sane comparison operator, `old_position != new_position` is equivalent to `old_position < new_position or old_position > new_position`